# How to interact with two matplotlib.axes.Axes together

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I made a 3 D animation with two different sets of axes declared as follows:

```
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d");
    ax = fig.add_axes(ax2.get_position(), projection="3d", frame_on=False, sharex=ax2, sharey=ax2)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    ax.axis("off")
    ax2.axis("off")
```

However, if I drag over the animation to change the perspective I'm looking at it from, only one set of axes moves and not both. How can I interact with the entire figure, so that when I drag my mouse both the sets of axes move?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a callback function that listens for mouse dragging and keeps the viewpoint of both axes in sync:

```
def on_move(event):
    ax2.view_init(elev=ax.elev, azim=ax.azim)

fig=plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d");
ax = fig.add_axes(ax2.get_position(), projection="3d", frame_on=False, sharex=ax2, sharey=ax2)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
```